# How to change label text that is outside the tableview when a button in the tableview is click

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The problem is i have a tableview with custom cells. Inside the cell, i have a button. When the button is click, it should change the label text that is outside the tableview.

Edit:
the label's text that I'm trying to change is on a different view. The ViewController has a tableview and a label view. Inside the tableview is a button and when it is click it changes the label's view text.

CustomCell and TableSource:

```
namespace Testing.iOS
{
    public partial class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
    {

        // Code omitted

        public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
        {  
            ViewController vc = new ViewController();

            public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CustomCell.Key) as CustomCell;

                if (cell == null) 
                {
                    cell = new CustomCell ();
                    var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CustomCell", cell, null);
                    cell = Runtime.GetNSObject( views.ValueAt(0) ) as CustomCell;
                }

                cell.btn.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
                {     
                    // Change label that is outside tableview
                    vc.updateLabel();
                };

                // Code omitted

                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View Controller:

```
namespace Testing.iOS
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {    
        public ViewController () : base ("ViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse (CustomCell.Nib, "CustomCell");
            tableView.Source = new CustomCell.TableSource();
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        }

        public void updateLabel()
        {
            label.Text = "testing";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem you are facing, from the question it is pretty straight to change labels text inside buttons action.

Comment: Problem is: I can't change the text that is outside the tableview when a button in the tableview is click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use protocols and delegates. 
First write a `CustomCellDelegate` protocol in `CustomCell` class with method `updateLabel()` also pass the `self` as one of the argument.

`-(void)updateLabelForCell:(UITabelViewCell *)cell;`

and in the `updateLabel()` method, call the delegate method

`[self updateLabelForCell:self];`

then in the `ViewController` class, implement the delegate method. based on the function called update the label. 
set your `ViewController` as delegate for the tableviewcell.

Comment: Can you go through, explain the last paragraph one more time, thank you.

Comment: i mean to say set `cell.delegate = self` in the `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` method. you can get the information about he cell since it is also passed in the delegate method

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method add following code

```
[CustomCell.buttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then handle your logic in BtnClicked method.

```
-(void)BtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender{

       labelOutlet.text = @"new text";

}
```

Comment: this does not work. the label is not in the tableviewcell

Comment: have you tried this code? It does not matter if label is outside tableview.

Comment: Your code is in Objective-C whereas I'm using C#. I can't translate the first line of code to C#

Comment: it does matter if it is outside the tableview. I can't call label.Text from TableSource cause label.Text is in the ViewController

Comment: Hey @MartDavious I can answer you only in Objective C or Swift iOS Languages. I don't know C#. It works 100% correct for iOS

Comment: @AvinashJadhav can you translate this in swift